# How to block access to a specific URL (<url-pattern> with wildcards *) at Tomcat

Tags: tomcat10

I followed [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-block-access-to-a-specific-url-at-tomcat-966668691.html) tutorial to block specific endpoints.

> In some cases, you may wish to restrict access to a specific URL

```
D:\CS\application\WEB-INF\web.xml

(..)
<security-constraint>  
<web-resource-collection>  
<web-resource-name>Protected API Members</web-resource-name>  
<url-pattern>/cs.exe/api/v*/members/*</url-pattern>  
<http-method>GET</http-method>  
</web-resource-collection>  
<auth-constraint />  
</security-constraint>  
</web-app>
```

The wildcard `v*` doesnt't work. Only the wildcard at the end `members/*` works. How-To specify wildcards in the middle of the API path.

Screenshot from IIS (we migrate the App to Tomcat):

[image]